# Removing Double space from a textbox using REGEX

Tags: javascript

Input:

```
"I want         to   remove        double     space    from    textbox."
```

Output:

```
"I want to remove double space from textbox."
```

---

```
function valid(f) {
     return f.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}
```

I have called this event `onblur="valid(this);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be accessing the value of the input... in your above code you're trying to run a regex on an input object.

```
function valid(f) {
     f.value=f.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s\s+/g,' ');
     return true;
}
```

Comment: @Sankalp the problem isn't the regex it's what you're trying to run it on (post updated)

Comment: @sankalp - It might be better to rename the function something like "clean" since it's really not validating anything  `onblur="clean(this);"`

Comment: though function is working correctly. But expanding same function I want to remove the space before new line. than wanna remove Double spaces for whole.
Its not good for particular sort of input.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return f.replace(/ +/,' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value of the textbox, and put the result back in the value:

```
onblur="this.value = valid(this.value);"
```